# Django pass CommaSeparated values to GET paramater

Tags: django, python-3.x

We know that django has CommaSeperated model field. But how can we pass commaSeparated string to Django GET parameter.

Whenever i try to pass something like below as GET parameter:

```
1,2,3,4
```

I receive using below code in django view

```
request.GET.get('productids','')
```

It ends up like below in django view.

```
'1,2,3,4'
```

Its ends up adding quotes around the array.

Please any Django experts help me with this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

```
param_list = request.GET.getlist('productids')
```

If you're passing it as a single parameter then you can construct it

```
param_list = [int(x) for x in request.GET.get('productids', '').split(',')]
```

Comment: That would work for a query string like `?product_ids=1&product_ids=2&...`. I think the OP has something like `?product_ids=1,2,3,4`

Comment: @Alasdair - Ah ok, if thats the case I think I might have answered that previously... I'll try to find it.

Comment: @Alasdair - I found it in a [comment you left previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483580/passing-a-list-through-url-in-django/35483756#comment58666329_35483756), I feel kind of wierd adding it to my own answer so if you wish to create your own answer with it I'd happily delete mine

Comment: There's already two answers, I don't think I need to add a third ;)

Comment: `param_list = [int(x) for x in request.GET.get('productids', []).split(',')]`  This worked like a charm

Comment: @Alasdair - Yes of course thanks! (Still feels like a weird answer..)

Answer (score 3):

Django converts GET and POST params to string (or unicode). That means, if you're sending a list (array) as a GET param, you'll end up getting a string at the backend.

However, you can convert the string back to array. Maybe like this:

```
product_ids = request.GET.get('productids', '')
ids_array = list(product_ids.replace(',', '')) # remove comma, and make list
```

The `ids_array` would look like this - `['1', '2', '3']`.

**Update:**

One thing worth noting is the ids in `ids_array` are strings, not integers (thanks to [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair) who pointed this out in the comments below). If you need integers, see the [answer by Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868470/django-pass-commaseparated-values-to-get-paramater/35868727#35868727).

Comment: That will give a list of strings, the OP wants a list of integers.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, that's right. But if OP needs to query products from DB, Django will automatically convert ids to integers.

Comment: We don't know that the op is going to use the array to query products from the db. Imagine they do `if 2 in ids_array:` -- that's going to behave differently if you haven't converted to integers.

Comment: @Alasdair That's a good case! I'll try and update accordingly.