# django many to many field filter using created time

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a model named `ClassRoom`,

```
class ClassRoom(model.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_lenth=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

and `view.py` like this.

```
def addstudents(request):
    class_room = ClassRoom.objects.get(id=1)
    class_name.students.add(request.user)
```

I added the students to `ClassRoom` like this.
I wanted to list all the students in class, who joined today.
How can I filter this students by **`their joining time`**?.

When we using django `ManyToManyField`, then django create an extra table in database. In that table contains `created` time. Can I filter using this field?

Comment: Define "joined today", how do you keep track of the day they joined?..

Comment: That is my problem. In database django created an extra table for this many2many. in that table contains created date. Can we filter using that table created field value?

Comment: Are you sure there is a `created` field? If it is, you can use it to filter

Comment: See the docs on [extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: So you could be able to use `class_room.students.filter(created=datetime.today())`, where `class_room` is a `ClassRoom` instance

Comment: @Gocht When I tried this. Then I got an error like this `Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field. Choices are:.....`

Comment: So it's not a field.

Comment: @Gocht but when I add a students to `ClassRoom`, django saved the time to `appname_classroom_students` table. There is no option for filtering using this time? :(

Comment: You haven't included any details about what `User` is, if its django's auth model then there isn't a `created` field. You should update your question to include the relevant information.

Comment: @Sayse the user is already created one. Now that user is added to a ClassRoom. User created time and user added to a ClassRoom time, both are different.

Comment: Again, the django auth [User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483580/passing-a-list-through-url-in-django/35483756#comment58666329_35483756) model does **not** have a `created` field, there is a `date_joined` which is about the closest thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can add extra fields to a M2M relationship table by using a custom table ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)).

```
class ClassRoom(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ClassMate')


class ClassMate(models.Model):
    class_room = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = model.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then you can do this:

```
class_room = ClassRoom.objects.get(...)

class_room.students.filter(date_joined=datetime.today())
```

Keep in mind that (as docs says) now you have to instance `ClassMate` objects to add a relationship:

```
class_room = ClassRoom.objects.get(...)
user = request.user
class_mate = ClassMate(class_room=class_room, user=user)
class_mate.save()
```

Comment: The user is already created one. Now that user is added to a ClassRoom. User created time and user added to a ClassRoom time, both are different.

Comment: The User created time is not here, `date_joined` will take the time when you create a `ClassMate` instance with `ClassRoom` and `User` instances